# Android app won't send post data to php file

Tags: php, android, http, post, send

I have a function in my Android app that sends data to a PHP file which inserts it into a database. My problem is that the post values never actually get sent to the PHP file.

My function looks like this:

```
public void postData(){

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(myURL);
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstName", "John"));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastName", "Doe"));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

          // show response in logcat
          String line = "";
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.i("postData", line);
           }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My php file is simply a check if the the variables were set:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["firstName"]) && isset($_POST["lastName"])) {

    // insert into the database

} else {

    // send error message.

}
?>
```

I always just get the error message from the else part of the PHP file. Does anybody know why this is happening or how to fix this?

Comment: What do you receive in $_REQUEST - can you log it?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could reside in a crossdomain policy file. The server must have a crossdomain.xml file that allows users outside the server to send data to it.

Google crossdomain.xml for more information.